# how i can do limit count of inputs before "@" for email in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

For example {limit [5-50] for here}@email.com

email@hotmail.com -> incorrect, because count of characters input smaller then 5
tryemail@hotmail.com -> correct

Can you explain the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe as simple as this:

```
local_part, domain = email.split('@')

local_part.length < 5
```

Though keep in mind many people do have short addresses, so don't get too strict here.

You could also do this with a regular expression:

```
email.match?(/\A[^@]{5,50}@[^@]+\z/)
```

Where that's an *extremely* lax parser.

Comment: It's working! Thanks for the solution.